# which container to use map or set or else?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, set

If using `std::map<std::string,object>` to keep objects ordered by name, the map's `value_type` (`std::pair<string,object>`) is a convenient class which warrants useful functionality, e.g.

```
typedef std::map<std::string,object> object_map;
typedef typename object_map::value_type named_object;
void function(named_object const&);

// with the following possible use case
void foo(std::string const&name, object_map const &omap)
{
  auto obj=omap.find(name);
  if(obj==omap.end()) throw std::runtime_error("name not found");
  function(*obj);
}
```

So far, so good. I later extend my objects

```
struct extended_object : object { /* more data */ };
```

and keep the extended objects ordered by name, too, via `std::map<std::string,extended>`.
I may define.

```
typedef std::map<std::string,extended_object> extended_object_map;
typedef typename extended_object_map::value_type named_extended_object;
```

Unfortunately, I cannot

```
void foo(std::string const&name, extended_object_map const& emap)
{
  auto eobj=emap.find(name);
  if(eobj==emap.end()) throw std::runtime_error("name not found");
  function(*eobj);        // cannot convert *eobj to const named_object&
}
```

**Now, my question** is how to solve this problem? I considered using a `reinterpret_cast<>`

```
  function(reinterpret_cast<const named_object&>(*eobj));
```

which essentially assumes that the data layouts of `named_object` and `named_extended_object` are exactly like that of base and derived. Is this safe/recommendable?
Alternatively, I considered to use `std::set` (instead of `std::map`) with key types
`named_object` and re-define

```
struct named_extended_object : named_object { /* more data */ };
```

The problem with this approach is that in order to `std::set::find()` an object, I must provide not just a name string, but a whole object or even extended object. According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find), `std::set::find()` will have a resolution to this problem in C++14 (overloads 3&4), but what shall I do in the mean time?

Comment: Try downloading a copy of the C++ specification which you can find a link to within this website: http://isocpp.org/get-started  then read up on reinterpret_cast.  I think that your conclusion will be that reinterpret_cast in that context makes no sense.  The types in question are std::pair where each has different types of object within it.  Reinterpret_cast is not going to help you here.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you understand what a set is.  A set is a key value pair but both the key and value are the same type, so of course you have to pass the one and only type object into find because it is the only possible way of finding anything.  A set cannot possibly help you in any way considering what you are trying to achieve.  The fact that the types within the std::pair relate through inheritance does not mean that you can simply cast from one pair type to another.  The language just doesn't support that.

Comment: @shawn1874 _"so of course you have to pass the one and only type object into find because it is the only possible way of finding anything."_ Not in C++14. See [N3657](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3657.htm) and the earlier [N3465](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3465.pdf) proposal it was based on.

Answer (score 1):

Change your function to

```
void function(const std::string& name, const object& obj);
```

Then call it like

```
auto obj = omap.find(name);
function(obj->first, obj->second);
// or
auto eobj = emap.find(name);
function(eobj->first, eobj->second);
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem, but merely avoids it. If `named_object` is a useful object for exposure in the public interface of my class, then this solution is not practical.

Comment: How is an object with member variables as undescriptive as `first` and `second` useful?

Comment: Not by itself, but if I declare a trivial derived class that only adds functionality but no data, so that I can cast to/from it without any issue.

Comment: @Walter '...without any issue' Depending on a derived class not to add data members is asking for trouble. If you only want to extend the functionality of the class, then use free functions, don't inherit from it.

Comment: what trouble? Can I not safe guard against the trouble at compile time?

Comment: @Walter 'what trouble?' Slicing. When you convert a `pair<string, extended_object>` to a `pair<string, object>` you loose the information from the derived class. To prevent that you need to pass a reference (or pointer) to the base class.

Comment: Sorry, but slicing is not issue here, as I only provide `const&` (slicing occurs when assigning to base from derived, whereby slicing off the additional members of derived). My `function()` cannot possibly suffer from that, it only needs to know about the `pair<string, object>` aspect of `pair<string, extended_object>`.

Comment: Based on the first response, it looks like the OP still wants to keep pounding a square block through a circular hole.

Answer (score 1):

> the map's `value_type` (`std::pair<string,object>`) is a convenient class which warrants useful functionality

N.B. that is **not** the map's `value_type`. It's `std::pair<const string,object>`

The `reinterpret_cast` results in undefined behaviour when a `named_extended_object` is accessed through the reference, it violates what some compilers call "strict aliasing" rules, and can cause your program to misbehave if the compiler optimises using type-based alias analysis. Do not use `reinterpret_cast` like that. In handwavy Liskov Substitution Principle terms, `extended_object` IS-A `object`, so it's OK to substitute an `extended_object` where an `object` is expected, but `pair<T, extended_object>` IS-NOT-A `pair<T, object>` so cannot be used interchangeably.

I like D Drmmr's answer, but if you don't want to do that, another option is a template:

```
template<typename Obj>
  void function(const std::pair<const std::string, Obj>&)
  {
    // ...
  }
```

This will accept `pair<const string, object>` and also `pair<const string, extended_object>` arguments. If the body of the template only tries to access the members that are present in `object` then it will work perfectly for both argument types.

If you don't want to expose that template to users of the function, then declare two overloads:

```
void function(const named_object&);
void function(const named_extended_object&);
```

Then in the implementation file:

```
namespace {
  template<typename Obj>
    void function_impl(const std::pair<const std::string, Obj>&)
    {
      // common implementation ...
    }
}

void function(const named_object& no) { function_impl(no); }
void function(const named_extended_object& neo) { function_impl(neo); }
```