# When is it okay to reinterpret a pair<A,B:C> as a pair<A,B>:C?

Tags: c++, derived-class, reinterpret-cast

(aside from the fact that `first` and `second` have different meanings---this issue can be suppressed.)

This is related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23407993/which-container-to-use-map-or-set-or-else). Suppose I have the following classes

```
struct object { /* some data */ };           // sizeof(object)   ==multiple of 16
struct more_data { /* some other data */ };  // sizeof(more_data)==multiple of 16
struct extended_object : object, more_data {};

struct named_object : private std::pair<std::string,object>
{
  std::string const&name() const { return first; }
  operator object const&() const { return second; }
};

struct named_extended_object : private std::pair<std::string,extended_object>
{
  std::string const&name() const { return first; }
  operator object const&() const { return second; }
  operator more_data const&() const { return second; }
}
struct extended_named_object : named_object, more_data {};
```

then `named_extended_object` and `extended_named_object` are similar. Indeed, their data layout should be identical. *[added in edit]* By making the `std::pair` bases private, I avoid exposing the `first` and `second` method, which would indeed return completely different things.

Is it safe to `reinterpret_cast<>` between them? How can I ascertain at compile time (using `static_assert(what here?)`) that it is?

**note** the alignment of `object` and `more_data` are both 8.

Comment: No, `named_extended_object` and `extended_named_object` are *nothing* alike. If you get the `second` member of `named_extended_object` you get an `extended_object` while on `extended_named_object` you get an `object`. The `extended_named_object` has the `more_data` structure as part of itself, which the `named_extended_object` class doesn't.

Comment: Example: Let more_data have stricter alignment then any other used type.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You're correct, but that's only because my question was too simple. I fixed my question to address this.

Comment: I see nothing in the definition of `reinterpret_cast` that would guarantee safety in this scenario. (Somewhat surprisingly, I couldn't even find a guarantee that `struct A { int; }; struct B { int; };` would lead to a valid `reinterpret_cast`able relation. It'll likely work in practice, of course, and that part could be checked with a combination of `sizeof`'s and `alignof`'s.